# How do I keep my texture when making my object low poly?

Tags: texturing

I'm creating a character for a low poly game in adobe fuse, then importing it into blender. I just wanna know how to keep the same texture of the high poly and apply it to the low poly so it still looks human, but in a TABS sort of way. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Adobe Fuse, but you can keep the high poly texture and use it to the low poly with the **baking** technique. After you unwrap the low poly model, just create a new blank texture in the *UV/Image Editor*. Make sure you have a material for the high poly with all needed textures, and another material for the low poly. In this material, add a texture image node (you don't have to connect it to another node, just create and place it) and choose the empty texture you created before.

[image: bakedmap]

Using *Cycles*, set the *Bake Type* to *Diffuse* (or any other property of the high poly's shader, if you need it) and active the *Selected to Active* checkbox. Click the high poly object **first**, then the low poly and eventually click *Bake*.

[image: bakepanel]

The texture you created before now contains information (the diffuse color in my example), and you can use it in the material of the low poly object (just connect the image texture node you created before to the shader node you need).